# Problems starting ios simulator with flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

Hi I have the following error trying to debug an ios simulator with flutter. I used the `flutter doctor` command and also `flutter doctor -v` but it tells me there is no error. I also tried doing a `flutter clean` and then `flutter run` but the error persists. Has someone else happened to? Beforehand thank you very much!

```
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           36,1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Failed to package /Users/pedrocarrasco/Desktop/nuevo.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
Exited (sigterm)
```